# Validating user input while timer is running in PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am making a `PHP` website with a game where users have to input some text into a form and then I need to check if that text matches the array stored in `$_SESSION["ptext"]`.

If the match isn't correct, then the user loses a life (`$_SESSION["lives"]`) and, as long as `$_SESSION["lives"] > 0`, the game continues, giving the user another chance. Thus, while this is being checked I don't want the user to be redirected to another page.

Also, I tried using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` as the `action` of the form but that reloads the page and restarts the timer, which I don't want. The code is in a file called `level1_1.php`, shown below:

```
<h5>Type answer here: </h5>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="userinput"></textarea>
<span> <?php echo $msg;?></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>

<?php
// validate user input
$userinput = "";

// if form submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // reduce user input to only letters and numbers
    $userinput = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST["userinput"]);

    // if incorrect, lose life
    if (strcasecmp($userinput, $_SESSION["ptext"]) != 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["lives"]--;

        // inform user
        $msg = "Sorry, that is incorrect. Please try again.";

        // if no more lives, game over!
        if ($_SESSION["lives"] == 0)
        {
            redirect("gameover.php");
        }

    }

    // otherwise, move on to next level
    else
    {
        $msg = "Great job! Get ready for the next level!";
        redirect("game.php");
    }  
}

?>
```

Comment: I miss a `session_start()` before you use `$_SESSION`!

Comment: I only copied the second part of the code, but session_start() is indeed called.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action ="" method="post">
```

instead of

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
```

put

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to submit the form using JS and AJAX.  You can make this easier by using jquery.  In order to do this nicely, you will want to put the logic for answering questions into a separate php file, which is not responsible for displaying anything, but returns one of a set of strings, e.g. correct, incorrect, out of lives etc...  The AJAX submitted form will post to this new page, and the response will be handled by the java script, forcing the user to an endgame scenario if appropriate.

More information of jquery's post method can be found here [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Seems promising, but how do I return a string from that php file??

Comment: Typically I would construct a json object string (relatively trivial in php) return that and parse it in jquery. There will be a bazillion guides if you Google those terms.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side so always will redirect the user.
Use something client side like JS(plus jQuery it helps).
Check docs:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Send ajax request and check the response.
Ajax request needs to have some authentication token to identify the user and the post action file needs to access the same session so session_start.

Basically you're searching to ajax requests, look more there.
Search- tons of examples.